# download of printer extension from pear

Tags: php, pear, php-extension

I am trying to install printer.dll file for php 5.3.13 version in wampp,i try to install pear using pear i tried to download printer package 
     $pear download printer

but getting error :No releases available for package "pear.php.net/printer"
download failed

if from pear printer.dll file is not available , from where to get this printer extension for version 5.3.13 , please help.t

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

printer is a pecl package, so the right way to install it is

```
$ pecl install printer
```

or

```
$ pear install pecl/printer
```

Now pecl does not ship windows dlls in their packages, so you cannot download it via pecl/pear at all on windows.

---

Note that the printer page has no releases, so you can't install it via pecl at all - http://pecl.php.net/package/printer

Comment: I get "No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/printer" install failed"